# Option to create App in Facebook Community Page

Tags: facebook

I have create a Facebook Community Page in Facebook. On the other side i have a web based mobile application built in jquery which supports Facebook Authentication ( like login using Facebook stuff)

Now to support facebook authentication i need to create a App in facebook and 
assign the `App ID/API Key` and set the `Site URL` but i don't see any option to create app in community page which i can see in my own personal normal facebook account as follows

Please look at the image , this is the way i set up an app using my personal facebook account but i dont see this option in community page tht i have created. how can i create app into that

**Step 1**

[image: Step One]

**Step 2**

[image: Step Two]

**Step 3**

[image]

In Community page i am getting following page when i try to create an app

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community pages are intended to be used like a wiki and Facebook does not allow for the creation of apps under community pages. So unfortunately you will have to use a personal account to create the app.